# How can I get button name, inside onClick method

Tags: android

How to get text pressed button, inside `onClick` method.
I can't use variable, cause it will change.

```
  Button[] mButtonsArray = new Button[MyArrayList.size()];
        for (Button b : mButtonsArray) 
        {
b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("name");
            b.setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                        {
                            MyClass.MyMethod(ButtonName);
                        }
                });
}
```

Comment: Isn't your `for` loop broken?  You expect `b` to be correctly assigned inside each array element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this inside the onclick method.

```
((Button) arg0).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTag` and `getTag`...

```
Button[] mButtonsArray = new Button[MyArrayList.size()];
    for (Button b : mButtonsArray) 
    {
b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("name");
        b.setTag("name");
        b.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        MyClass.MyMethod((String)arg0.getTag());
                    }
            });
}
```

Comment: That `for (Button b : mButtonsArray)` doesn't look right to me.  The contents of the array haven't been initialised yet.  You'll need to use `for (int i = 0; i < mButtonsArray.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use

```
b.setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                        {
                            MyClass.MyMethod(((Button) arg0).getText().toString());
                        }
                });
```

It will be simple that way.

Comment: Instead of b.getText(), which will require b to be final or a global variable, it would be better to use the arg0 to cast it to a Button and use it's getText() method

Comment: @biddulph.r, Agree :) Edited

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `setTag()` and `getTag()` here,

```
b.setTag("name");
```

And to fetch it use,

```
  b.setOnClickListener(
     new OnClickListener() 
    {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            String name = (String)arg0.getTag();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
Button[] mButtonsArray = new Button[MyArrayList.size()];
        for (Button b : mButtonsArray) 
        {
b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("name");
            b.setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                        {
                            Button b=(Button)arg0;
                            name=b.getText();
                        }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b.setOnClickListener(
         new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   String name = ((Button) arg0).getText().toString();
              }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get by using getText() on arg0 by convering it to button type like below.

```
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) 
 {
  Button btn = (Button)arg0;
  if(btn != null)
MyClass.MyMethod(btn.getText());
  }
```

});